# DataGrip org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

Tags: groovy, datagrip

I am unable to run some basic groovy code with abstraction. I have read thru this [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/02/13/generate-pojos/) and auto generated pojos and rest controllers from Data Grip.

1. On DataGrip I right-click, hit "Scripted Extensions" and
2. select a Groovy file. If the file is written exactly as "Groovy Pojos.groovy" (see in link) then it works.
3. If I want to use some basic abstraction and designs around reusability it fails to work. Cant even get to import classes in Groovy.

Simple code snippet of what I tried

```
class abstract AGenerate {
abstract def getPackageName() ;
abstract def getFileSuffix() ;
abstract def generateClassFiles()
abstract def generate(output, className, fields) ;
def typeMapping = [
(~/(?i)int/) : "Integer",
(~/(?i)bigint/) : "Long",
(~/(?i)float/): "Double", : "Float",
(~/(?i)double|decimal|real/) : "Double",
(~/(?i)datetime|timestamp/) : "java.sql.Timestamp",
(~/(?i)date/) : "java.sql.Date",
(~/(?i)time/) : "java.sql.Time",
(~/(?i)/) : "String"
]
...  

package com.companyname.autogenerate ;
import com.intellij.database.model.DasTable
import com.intellij.database.model.ObjectKind
import com.intellij.database.util.Case
import com.intellij.database.util.DasUtil
FILES.chooseDirectoryAndSave("Choose directory", "Choose where to store generated files") { dir ->
    SELECTION.filter { it instanceof DasTable && it.getKind() == ObjectKind.TABLE }.each { generateFolderFromTable(it, dir) }
}
class GenerateEntityClass extends AGenerate {
    def getFileSuffix() {
        return "Entity.java"
    }
    def getPackageName() {
        return "com.sample;" ;
    }
...
```

Notice I have defined a super class AGenerate and then child classes GenerateEntityClass, I get a error when try to run AutoGenerate at the import line itself

```
import com.intellij.database.model.DasTable
import com.intellij.database.model.ObjectKind

import com.mycompany.autogenerate.GenerateEntityClass

 def GenerateEntityClass entityClass = new GenerateEntityClass();
        FILES.chooseDirectoryAndSave("Choose directory", "Choose where to store generated files") { dir ->        
            SELECTION.filter { it instanceof DasTable && it.getKind() == ObjectKind.TABLE }.each { entityClass.generateFolderFromTable(it, dir) }
        }
```

I get an error

> 12:06 AM AutoGenerate.groovy:
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
> startup failed: Script24.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class
> com.companyname.autogenerate.GenerateEntityClass @ line 4, column 1. import
> com.companyname.autogenerate.GenerateEntityClass;

Edit: Folder Structure
Project

```
-->scripts
----->AutoGenerate.groovy (call this from DataGrip)
----->com
-------->companyname
----------->autogenerate
-------------->AGenerate.groovy
-------------->GenerateEntityClass.groovy
-->src
```

Comment: Where is `AGenerate` located? Groovy just says that it is not in your classpath

Comment: AGenerate.groovy is in a folder com/companyname/autogenerate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason abstractions dont work. So I just separated the scripts in different files (ones that change and ones that done) and used a bash script to concat. For now this should work. Until someone answers this in a better way this works.